# html <video> doesn't play sound on some videos

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, angular

I don't understand, I have a project with Angular2 and in my home component, I try to display a video with html5. The problem is that sometimes, on some videos, the tag doesn't play sound:

```
<div class="video-gallery">
  <video id="video" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="420" poster="assets/imgs/video_logo.png" >
  <source src="assets/videos/{{videos[0].name + videos[0].extension}}" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</div>
```

When I say 'on some videos' I mean it's not up to the extension, some videos are mp4 and play sound and others (mp4) don't. Same thing for mkv for example. I only get the video but no sound. What could be the problem ? I work with Chrome's last version so I don't think it's from chrome because it is supposed to support video and sound of html5 . Can it be from the video tag ?
Thanks

Comment: what codec is used for the audio track in the files that don't work - also, is there any messages in the developer tools console that may be telling you what the problem is

Comment: The codec that doesn't work is audio AC3.
And no I got nothing in the console, all is clean...

Comment: Read [supported codecs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) - no browser supports AC3 audio

Comment: Ok thank you, I didn't see that

Comment: Maybe it will come in 2017 https://www.quora.com/When-do-Dolbys-AC-3-patents-expire-so-that-licensing-is-no-longer-required